# range.formula not accepting string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to feed a vlookup formula into a range but it doesn't seem to be accepting the string. What am I missing here?

```
Dim inBudget As Range, lookupValue As String, result As String, inForm As String
Set inBudget = Range("C8")
Set dataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set reportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
For j = 1 To 3
'' change 3 to years using current data -2016 +1
    For i = 1 To 12
    lookupValue = 2015 + j & dptNum & "BudgetRCPT$"
    inForm = "=vlookup(" & lookupValue & ",Data!A2:AK" & dataLastRow & "," & CStr(11 + i) & ")"
    Debug.Print inForm
    inBudget.Formula = inForm
    Set inBudget = inBudget.Offset(0, 1)
    Next i
Next j
```

How dataLastRow is calculated

```
dataLastRow = LastRow("A")

Function LastRow(colName As String) As Long 'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range(colName & CStr(.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
    End With End Function
```

Comment: I don't see where you declare or assign a value to `dataLastRow`

Comment: Ah sorry I declare it earlier. It's an integer.

Comment: please show the declaration and how it is assigned a value in the original post

Comment: Solved the issue. It was not having quotes around the first argument of the vlookup. How should I go about closing the question?

Comment: You can either delete the question or, add a detailed answer that shows the code fixed and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue was not having quotes around the vlookup value.

```
    For j = 1 To 3
'' change 3 to years using current data -2016 +1
    For i = 1 To 12
    lookupValue = Chr(34) & 2015 + j & dptNum & "BudgetRCPT$" & Chr(34)
    inForm = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookupValue & ",Data!A2:AK" & dataLastRow & "," & CStr(11 + i) & ")"
    Debug.Print inForm
    inBudget.Formula = inForm
    Set inBudget = inBudget.Offset(0, 1)
    Next i
Next j
```

The first argument of a vlookup needs to be enclosed in brackets. I have added Chr(34) to resolve this.